# Is there a way to know the build of a random AI after a match?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to know a random AI's build in *Starcraft 2* after a match, like in the replay. Is there a way to do this?

I don't want to spoil matches by defining the build of the AI when starting the match, but I'm curious. :) Of course, I can guess the build based on the actions, but I would like to know it for sure. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

During the replay you can see what they are building at every moment of the game by looking at the production overlay. You'd need a little more advanced knowledge of the build orders (which isn't hard to find on the internet) to determine what they are aiming for as a build order.